# Use the remainder estimation theorem to find the maximum value of error?

Tags: taylor-expansion

[image]

My answer for part (bi) was $\frac{x}{2}$ - $\frac{x^2}{4}$

My attempt for part b(ii) was to find $\frac{g^{'''}(z)}{3!}$($x^3$) = $\frac{8}{3!(2+2z)^3}$ where z ∈ [0, $\frac{1}{2}$]. To find the maximum value of this, I set z=0 (since the fraction with the smallest denominator will have the largest value). This resulted in $\frac{1}{3!}$= $\frac{1}{6}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $(i)$, that's correct.

For $(ii)$, first we have to find $M$. $g^{(3)}(x) = \frac1{(x+1)^3}$. The upper bound of that on $I$ is $1$, so $M = 1$. That gives us our bound of: $\frac{M|x|^3}{3!} = \frac{x^3}{6}$. The upper bound of *that* on $I$ is $\frac{1}{48}$.